# Is OpenFDA for Food Recall Enforcement Reports [/food/enforcement] bulk download supports in TLS 1.2 enabled servers?

Tags: openfda

The bulk download with below link is not working in TLS 1.2 enabled servers. Can someone help me to understand whether OpenFDA bulk download supports in TLS 1.2 enabled servers? Or do I needs to use its API instead of bulk download.

https://download.open.fda.gov/food/enforcement/food-enforcement-0001-of-0001.json.zip

Thanks

Comment: It works now when we access the FDA through the TLS1.2 servers. Just out of curiosity, have there been any changes at the FDA level in the use of TLS1.2?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late reply, but are you still encountering this issue? I've checked our configuration, which has TLS 1.2 & 1.3 enabled and see no errors.

Regards,

Violet Wren, openFDA Tech Lead